# Rethinking the torrent of trash: quarantine for new user questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

TL;DR: Please reconsider the idea of a quarantine for new users' questions.

Consider two pictures.

Our first contestant is a person with a problem, and a disinclination to do any real research or even build a decent question. Perhaps this person is lazy. Perhaps he or she did not get very much professional training. Perhaps this person has some other reason to worship at a cargo cult. Whatever the background, this person has a problem, has no solution, and is looking for the fastest, least-effort, path to 'a solution,' defined as some codez.

But, there is a light in the darkness. This person has heard of a wonderful place on the internet. A place where, amongst [the buzzing of the bees in the cigarette trees](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/obrotherwhereartthou/inthebigrockcandymountains.htm), there are <del>suckers</del> people who *will send the codez*. So, of course, our person buzzes over to stackoverflow.com and deposits a question.

Let me give you the bad news. You can't prevent them from coming. The lure is too strong. And you can't discourage them with downvotes, close votes, or nasty notes. They have nothing to lose, and something to gain. Even if you do manage to discourage any single individual (or block that individual), *there are millions more where that person came from*.

Time for our second contestant. Here we have a person who is not a unreformable cargo-cultist, but has not thought very hard about what it means to ask the entire bloody internet for help. And to make matters worse, this person has read the word 'community' here and there in relation to stackoverflow.com. So, when the person writes a question that is incomplete, somewhat incoherent, or off-topic, the response may be swift and negative, because the responder is completely fed up with dealing with people like the first contestant.

Rinse, lather, and repeat, and then read endless postings here from people decrying all the questions from the first species and other people decrying the rough treatment accorded to the second.

We get nowhere debating whether downvotes are mean, or a 'weapon', or even whether acerbic commentary has a place. What the site needs is *mechanism* that spares the answering experts from the former group while leaving some slack for the later. It seems to me that various long-standing suggestions could be reconsidered in this light. One that springs to mind is some sort of quarantine for new-user questions: don't even put them on the front page until they have been reviewed. People with patience and inclination can review them, and can, if they choose, try to help the help-able to ask questions that deserve to be on the front page. People who are fresh out of patience can ignore this queue.

Comment: Could you give a concise topic/picture/vision please? Give me an [elevator pitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_pitch)!

Comment: Propose something concrete.  I'm personally convinced that we're well past the point where we can leave polluters to dump their trash anonymous.  Getting a nick ought to be an earned privilege, until then it should match the name on the email account you register with. For example.

Comment: I *think* that this is a [tag:feature-request], but remove the tag if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I did. How is quarantine non-concrete? You'd never see a question until some other volunteer licked it into shape.

Comment: I think what SO is missing is a _streamlined, low effort_ way to quickly delete homework dumps _that doesn't take close votes_. [Like one we've got at Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6845/31260): just one copy-paste into comments field, one copy paste into flag message and vote down which is refunded when dump is deleted. (at the scale of SO though I think this would soon end in moderators requesting a dedicated flag for homework dumps but that's a different story)

Comment: @gnat I don't really get it. All you're doing is using a pre-written flag message, but it's still a flag that has to be processed by a moderator. I could easily write up that message in the flag box (and have before), but it will still take time to be processed. I don't see how this is streamlined or low-effort.

Comment: @CodyGray ideally, there would be a dedicated flag for homework dumps (similar to spam); what we have over there is just close enough. _Guaranteed quick deletion_ is critically important from perspective of flagger: this ensures that no matter how many spammers attack us, downvotes on their dumps will refund and one will be able to continue rating real content. _Low effort_ is also very important: spending more than few seconds on homework trash would be terribly unfair, not to mention that this wouldn't scale

Comment: "A reliable system... would cover... front page, questions and tag pages etc.

At these pages, system would limit visibility of potentially troublesome questions only to users with _reasonably proven ability and explicit desire_ to evaluate such content..." ([Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage algorithm, phase 3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274602/839601))

Answer (score 6):

What you're proposing seems quite vague and I'm not sure if even *you* understand what you're asking for. The problem with fragmenting Stack Overflow like this is that your experience before and after you've "graduated" is different.

Posting a question and allowing someone to come along and fix seems fine on paper, but that gives new users the idea that they can just throw something up on Stack Overflow and that someone will make it acceptable for them. **They should learn to do that by themselves, or they will never learn to use this site effectively**.

If no one sees their question before someone fixes it for them, then the question would theoretically be fine by the time it is "released" to Stack Overflow, which makes the OP exempt from the community's wrath (grammar fixed, unclarity resolved, etc.). However, the OP *didn't fix it themselves*, which means that they'll just post it the same way next time, unbeknownst to the fact that there are downvotes and close votes awaiting them.

Another problem is that Stack Overflow is about getting answers to your questions *quickly*. If it sits for even five or ten minutes in a queue, that's five or ten wasted minutes in which the OP has probably left and will not be available to clarify his/her question.

---

So, let's remove the time aspect from the request and just put new posts in front of people who are willing to review them.

[Oh, wait](//stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts).

Yes, that already exists: questions from new users *already* go to the First Posts queue for anyone with 500+ reputation to review. Unfortunately, many take this privilege lightly and it is the queue where people most often fail review audits. The No Action Needed option is a last resort, and you should really consider that you're the only user who will ever see this person's first post in a review before you make the decision to press that button.

The reason why you probably didn't think of this queue when posting this question is because it is severely underestimated and it doesn't do much good because people reviewing there take their reviews much too lightly.