# Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 3 - algorithm tweaks

Tags: discussion, question-quality, homepage, se-quality-project

After [phase 2 feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269769/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-2), we've made a few tweaks to how recent hot questions are chosen, namely to **better incorporate your tag preferences**.

Here's a debug page that highlights which questions are hot in a pleasing bisque:

> https://stackoverflow.com/home/recommended/debug

While the homepage will have caching, the debug page currently doesn't; refreshing will pick another batch from the last several thousand questions that were asked (and are answered and upvoted), allowing you to better gauge what will be consistently selected for you.

We're mostly happy with this iteration and will be moving soon to A/B test its results - don't worry, we won't go live without detailing how the tests went (or if we'll even make any changes).

So, does [this recommended tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended) look better than your current [interesting tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting)

Comment: Yes, it's definitely *much* better now.

Comment: Oh yes this is nice.

Comment: Much, much better! Well done!

Comment: The mere fact that I can now filter what shows up based on whether or not it's been answered already wins my vote.

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: Lost a couple of on hold questions and some bounties in subjects I know nothing about and gained a couple of the hottest questions over the last 24 hours... _much_ better than the previous iteration!

Comment: This does look so much better!

Comment: *Very* good. I've already answered a couple questions off that page!

Comment: Much more useful!

Comment: "Here's a debug page" pure awesomesausage.

Comment: It's much better, but I get a result for `excel` in both pages that isn't interesting for me. I have ignored all tags for windows and ms-office (not the sub-ones for word, excel ...) so I don't want to see excel results (and there were no other tag in the question that I marked as a favorite)

Comment: I like it. I immediately got the _feeling_ it was more useful, and more pertinent. I did not check if it was a founded feeling, though :-)

Comment: I am still getting a hell of a lot of questions which do not appear on any tags I actually use

Comment: I actually never noticed the `Interesting` tab :P But I started using the new one and already answered a question and forgot I was using a new link xD Great stuff! (but the debug one looks weird, the old format seems ok to me, but I might be missing something :P).

Comment: Is there any chance that dev page can stay around, like, forever? I really like the condensed title format, it's quickly scannable.

Comment: am I the only one that actually _likes_ the table grid layout thats there currently?  Kinda nice, no flufff.

Comment: Recommended looks better than interesting. There are stuff on Interesting that don't have any of the tags I set as favorite nor I have any idea how appeared to me. On Recommended I've seen just one question that has nothing to do with my Fav tags (Xcode question) but other than that, all others were tag relevant.

Comment: @iamkrillin I like it as well, but not to keep; maybe a mix between what we have now and that debug table. I do love being able to see way more data at a glance without needing to scroll. Most of all, I like that I can filter by my favorite tags on the debug page (I can't on the regular one).

Comment: The link doesn't work for me. Boo hoo!

Comment: @0x499602D2 yeah, I'm seeing issue in a calculation that is now cached for a bit.  Investigating.

Comment: @0x499602D2 a fix has been deployed; thanks for reporting the error.

Comment: I'm getting Oded in the corner when I try to visit that page now :(

Comment: Is the debug URL supposed to be available on all sites, or only on [so]? It works on all [se] sites at the moment. (@Undo)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi while it is enabled on all sites, only Stack Overflow has certain machine learning algorithms running to correctly classify a user's tag preferences, so results will vary a bit more.

Comment: I guess it's ok for the beta, but that page is *really* slow for me.

Answer (score 19):

Might be a minor thing, but a way to filter out messages that are closed (especially under **Needs Answer**) would be helpful

Great layout overall

Answer (score 8):

I see more questions that I would like to read, so ... good job.

But...
This is maybe out-of-scope for the current set of improvements, as it probably will require an entirely different algorithm/approach. However, it may be a good suggestion for further improvements.

I have still a difficult time finding questions that I would like to answer. For me, most of the questions there are too "easy": questions you could easily answer in a few lines, or with a quick google search.

I personally look for questions and answers with more depth; I know, it's probably a personal preference, but it should show from my answer history.
If I prefer to answer to long, elaborated questions from users with high rep, I probably like "hard" questions; same if my answers are long and convoluted: I might be interested in answering a long, well written question which has only a short, almost-link-only (or code-only) question.

My 2 cents

EDIT:
Let me make an example.

This question is in my list ([C# command line add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804187/c-sharp-command-line-add-reference-to-microsoft-office-interop-excel))

- Is it relevant to my favorites? Yes, I have C# among my favorite tags.
- Is it a question worth answering? Yes, I suppose. Simple questions do find a place on SO.
- Could I answer it? Definitely
- Would I answer it? No... It's just not my cup of tea.

This question ([How to convert an event to an IObservable when it doesn't conform to the standard .NET event pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768370/how-to-convert-an-event-to-an-iobservable-when-it-doesnt-conform-to-the-standar)) and this one ([Y-combinator implementation in javascript and elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803860/y-combinator-implementation-in-javascript-and-elixir)) are also in my list. And I like both of them (acutally, I was answering the first one  but someone was faster...)

Could an algorithm see it? Probably yes, using a combination of question score, my history, question length...

It is not simple; indeed, there are some very difficult tags. Javascript, for example, and to a lesser extent C#. I do like Javascript, the language, and C#, the language. I do not like questions about web page fiddling or about windows forms controls. They are entirely legitimate questions, but they are beginner's questions and I do not have time (unfortunately) to answer all the questions I *can* answer. Distinguish among them is quite hard. Understand if I, as a user, prefer "hard" or "simple" questions is hard as well. But someone can always wish it, right? :)

I wonder: how high-rep users (Eric Lippert, Jon Skeet, Mark Gravell, Hans Passant.. to quote e few active under the C# tag) find questions they like to answer?

Comment: I think that's more a problem with how people ask questions on SO in general than anything that can/should be fixed by the homepage algorithm.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I thing that it's not entirely a problem on the "quality" of questions: there are good questions which are simple, and require a simple answer. It's a question of "preference", and "discover" what the user prefers. I edited to include an example.

Answer (score 3):

> So, does this recommended tab look better than your current interesting tab?

Not really, I still am getting questions I shouldn't like: [error ios device addingg in wso2 emm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783751/error-ios-device-addingg-in-wso2-emm)

I don't even know those tags, I don't think they even exist on my profile, and if they do they were accidently answered.

Also this is of no interest to me: [Emulating aspect-fit behaviour using AutoLayout constraints in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766747/emulating-aspect-fit-behaviour-using-autolayout-constraints-in-xcode-6)

Nor is: [Couldnt load module: undefinded symbol: dissector_add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783944/couldnt-load-module-undefinded-symbol-dissector-add)

So it looks the same, not worse but also not particularly awesome either.

Comment: You can always put in ignored tags. :-X

Comment: @Michael true that thugh you could say that the algorithm should be intelligent enough, with my activity, to know what I like to read

Comment: That first question is one that *no one* should like. We should be filtering that kind of stuff out before it ever gets posted, not just sweeping it under the rug by hiding it from our top answerers.

Comment: +1 Same for me. I've got a haskell question appearing for some reason ([What can I do to make this ghci infereced signature to compile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25802223)). I have never answered such a question, AFAIK. I know nothing about the language or any of the tags. Also [How to compile clojurescript to nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25803420) appears - another question I can't fathom. On the whole, the noise ration has improved though.

Answer (score 3):

As of the instant this answer was posted, the link https://stackoverflow.com/home/recommended/debug is sporadically generating an error. Sometimes when I go there, it works, but in other small cases, I see an error page instead. I'm pretty sure that this was working before; so why is it generating an error at times?

Comment: Anyone else able to repro?

Comment: I've got a log of the exception; investigating...

Comment: @JarrodDixon What caused the exception?

Comment: As usual, looks like an issue w/ caching.  A fix has been deployed that hopefully prevents the blowup.

Comment: @JarrodDixon What's the specific revision?

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to see something that felt more curated, that was like a friend saying "hey, did you see this interesting question". I don't see the difference between what's in "Recommended" now and just going to my favourite tag (which is what I do now). It doesn't make me want to look at any of the questions. It doesn't save me effort.

My suggestions:

- Focus less on question age. Focus more on quality. Don't just put up the newest questions, put up the best questions and answers from the previous 24 hours. How can you call a question with down votes "Recommended"?
- Allow questions to bubble up instead of being bumped down after a few minutes (use votes, views, stars, shares, inbound clicks and comments to determine rank).
- Show a snippet of the question and a snippet of the top answer. The list of titles is just unappealing. Use fancy JavaScript to hide snippets for anyone that wants it that way.
- Some users consistently provide great questions and answers. Highlight those people.
- Allow me to favourite users so I can see their recent answers.
- Put in a control to let me see the best from the previous 24H, 3 days, 1 week and 1 month.
- Allow mods and high rep users to actually highlight interesting content. This is different from an upvote or favourite. It says "this is interesting and should be seen".

I'm guessing that your idea of recommended is different that mine. You're wondering about how to get people to answer these questions. I'm wondering about how I can find interesting answers to read.

Answer (score 2):

Minor bug, I think. If I click 'toggle *x* more favorites', it expands to show *x* more favorite tags. The toggle remains titled 'toggle *x* more favorites', even though clicking it a second time will show *x* **fewer** favorites.

Comment: It is a "debug" page...

Comment: That is what toggle means...

Comment: @CJDennis - Toggle means "activate". When I click a button that says "toggle (activate) 4 more favorites" I don't expect 4 options to disappear! The word "more" should become "less" once all are shown. Well, "fewer" I guess since it's countable.

Comment: Toggle means "switch from one effect, feature, or state to another"... So when none are shown, "Toggle x more favorites" means ON, and when they are shown "Toggle x more favorites" means OFF. It would be different if it said "show" or "display".

Comment: @polarysekt sounds like it is ambiguous enough that it should be rephrased

Comment: As the sentence does not specify which favourites it's talking about it can both be interpreted as toggling another set of favourites or the previous set of favourites. The existance of the word 'more' however implies the former of the two, thus I am with Roddy here.

Comment: Just drop the `more` and stick with `toggle x favourites`, that way everyone's happy.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable system would not be limited to "recommended/interesting/hot" pages but instead, would cover *all* the typically used ones: front page, questions and tag pages etc.

At these pages, system would limit visibility of potentially troublesome questions only to users with *reasonably proven ability and explicit desire* to evaluate such content - for example to users over particular reputation (500... 1K... 2K) who additionally *consciously* picked an option to view such content.

Comment: "**out of sight, out of mind**... Make low-quality questions less visible _immediately_. Don't wait until they get downvoted - figure out if they're problematic and immediately tuck them out of sight until/unless they're fixed. Not _just_ on the homepage, but on tag pages as well..." ([quote source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242044/165773))