# Stack Overflow frontpage tailored for each user?

Tags: support, questions, front-page

Just today, I've observed that the frontpage of Stack Overflow shows me questions regarding HTML, Python and PHP (questions that I generally answer).

So, is Stack Overflow tracking the questions that I answer and showing me similar questions on the homepage?

Comment: I'm not requesting a new feature, I'm asking if that feature exists...

Comment: I actually didn't even know it exists before your comment, so thanks... @lostsock

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking at the "Interesting" tab.  Which attempts to show you questions that you might find interesting.  Based on the preferences you selected in your profile.  Or what you've previously showed an interest in, it remembers what tags you posted to.

Use the Questions button to see everything, filtered by tags that you selected as undesirable.  But keep in mind that there are a great many questions asked every minute, it is going to fire-hose your brain pretty quickly.  Edit the preferences in your profile to customize the views.

Comment: When did they even roll this out?

Comment: Years ago, I can't remember the exact date.

Comment: I'm a part of SO for about a year and haven't noticed it till today..

Comment: Yes, works pretty well doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. And because of it I don't have to use the search bar that often, but why was I unable to use the feature till today?

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi if you haven't notice until it today, there is a possibility you are part of [AB testing of the feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271128/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-algorithm-phase-3) '@lostsock mentioned earlier.  What is the name of the "tab" on the page?  Intersting?  Or Recommended?