# Why is StackOverflow's "Interesting" Question tab not present on more Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, user-experience

In [this blog post from 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/), Jeff Atwood revealed the recent redesign of the Stack Overflow homepage.

In 2010, the homepage was changed to display a set of questions personalised to your preferences, rather than just the most recently active questions.

To quote Jeff:

> The goal is no longer to show you a simple flat list of the last (n) active questions — that’s not even possible any more based on sheer question volume — but, instead, to narrow the list to a subset of active questions that we think you will be interested in.

So my question is this: why isn't this feature present on other Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll quote from [the answer I gave when this question was raised on Physics' Meta a while back](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/add-interesting-questions-tab-to-front-page/4385#4385):

> The current setup for the "interesting" tab looks at the last 3,000 posts, using [various user- and post-specific metrics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/add-interesting-questions-tab-to-front-page/4385#4385) to display 90 personalized posts; that makes sense, since Stack Overflow gets over twice that every day. We could look at less than that, but...
>
> ...At 42 questions per day, Physics.SE's homepage already displays most recent activity on the site... to *everyone*. The logic used for the "interesting" tab as it's currently set up wouldn't accomplish much.

This still applies to [most sites other than Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) - and while it's possible that Mathematics, Super User and Ask Ubuntu could benefit from a more nuanced display of questions, we've come to believe that [the current "Interesting" algorithm isn't really ideal even on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so); a system that doesn't skew *quite* as much toward displaying recent, unanswered posts regardless of quality is [under development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271128/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-algorithm-phase-3), and - while currently focused on the specific needs of Stack Overflow - might eventually be more suitable for use network-wide.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the excellent answer. I will definitely be spending some time on the ["Recommended" view debug page](http://stackoverflow.com/home/recommended/debug) [linked by Jarrod](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271128/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-algorithm-phase-3).